# Maya: Query constraint information while foster node

Tags: python-2.7, maya

In Maya is there a way to query the source and target of a constraint while it is a foster node?

I'm trying to diagnose an issue where the connection is lost after becoming a foster parent so I need the intermediary information to compare against a constraint that is working.

All methods I've come across require the connection to be established but while it's a foster node those don't exist.  Maya is able to restore the connections so that information must exist somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can attempt to identify the constraints by going through the reference's edits. Open up the reference editor then run File->List reference edits. This will pop-up a new window that will display all of its edits that took place outside of the reference. This list can be potentially huge, so you can type in the constraint's name to filter the results.

Now if you're attempting to access this via script, you can use `cmds.referenceQuery`.

Pass the reference node, not the foster parent, to these commands:

```
edit_strings = cmds.referenceQuery("YOUR-REF-NODE", editStrings=True)
edit_nodes = cmds.referenceQuery("YOUR-REF-NODE", editNodes=True)
edit_attrs = cmds.referenceQuery("YOUR-REF-NODE", editAttrs=True)

for line, node, attr in zip(edit_strings, edit_nodes, edit_attrs):
    print line, " ::: ", node, ":::", attr
```

The results that print out will be like the following:

```
parent -s -r "|CHR_alienB001_001RNfosterParent1|globalSRT_CTRL_parentConstraint1" "|CHR_alienB001_001:ROOT_NUL|CHR_alienB001_001:RIG_NUL|CHR_alienB001_001:globalSRT_NUL|CHR_alienB001_001:globalSRT_CTRL"  :::  |CHR_alienB001_001RNfosterParent1|globalSRT_CTRL_parentConstraint1 ::: constraintTranslateX
connectAttr "|CHR_alienB001_001RNfosterParent1|globalSRT_CTRL_parentConstraint1.constraintTranslateX" "|CHR_alienB001_001:ROOT_NUL|CHR_alienB001_001:RIG_NUL|CHR_alienB001_001:globalSRT_NUL|CHR_alienB001_001:globalSRT_CTRL.translateX"  :::  |CHR_alienB001_001:ROOT_NUL|CHR_alienB001_001:RIG_NUL|CHR_alienB001_001:globalSRT_NUL|CHR_alienB001_001:globalSRT_CTRL ::: translateX
connectAttr "|CHR_alienB001_001RNfosterParent1|globalSRT_CTRL_parentConstraint1.constraintTranslateY" "|CHR_alienB001_001:ROOT_NUL|CHR_alienB001_001:RIG_NUL|CHR_alienB001_001:globalSRT_NUL|CHR_alienB001_001:globalSRT_CTRL.translateY"  :::  |CHR_alienB001_001RNfosterParent1|globalSRT_CTRL_parentConstraint1 ::: constraintTranslateY
connectAttr "|CHR_alienB001_001RNfosterParent1|globalSRT_CTRL_parentConstraint1.constraintTranslateZ" "|CHR_alienB001_001:ROOT_NUL|CHR_alienB001_001:RIG_NUL|CHR_alienB001_001:globalSRT_NUL|CHR_alienB001_001:globalSRT_CTRL.translateZ"  :::  |CHR_alienB001_001:ROOT_NUL|CHR_alienB001_001:RIG_NUL|CHR_alienB001_001:globalSRT_NUL|CHR_alienB001_001:globalSRT_CTRL ::: translateY
connectAttr "|CHR_alienB001_001RNfosterParent1|globalSRT_CTRL_parentConstraint1.constraintRotateX" "|CHR_alienB001_001:ROOT_NUL|CHR_alienB001_001:RIG_NUL|CHR_alienB001_001:globalSRT_NUL|CHR_alienB001_001:globalSRT_CTRL.rotateX"  :::  |CHR_alienB001_001RNfosterParent1|globalSRT_CTRL_parentConstraint1 ::: constraintTranslateZ
connectAttr "|CHR_alienB001_001RNfosterParent1|globalSRT_CTRL_parentConstraint1.constraintRotateY" "|CHR_alienB001_001:ROOT_NUL|CHR_alienB001_001:RIG_NUL|CHR_alienB001_001:globalSRT_NUL|CHR_alienB001_001:globalSRT_CTRL.rotateY"  :::  |CHR_alienB001_001:ROOT_NUL|CHR_alienB001_001:RIG_NUL|CHR_alienB001_001:globalSRT_NUL|CHR_alienB001_001:globalSRT_CTRL ::: translateZ
connectAttr "|CHR_alienB001_001RNfosterParent1|globalSRT_CTRL_parentConstraint1.constraintRotateZ" "|CHR_alienB001_001:ROOT_NUL|CHR_alienB001_001:RIG_NUL|CHR_alienB001_001:globalSRT_NUL|CHR_alienB001_001:globalSRT_CTRL.rotateZ"  :::  |CHR_alienB001_001RNfosterParent1|globalSRT_CTRL_parentConstraint1 ::: constraintRotateX
connectAttr "|CHR_alienB001_001:ROOT_NUL|CHR_alienB001_001:RIG_NUL|CHR_alienB001_001:globalSRT_NUL|CHR_alienB001_001:globalSRT_CTRL.rotateOrder" "|CHR_alienB001_001RNfosterParent1|globalSRT_CTRL_parentConstraint1.constraintRotateOrder"  :::  |CHR_alienB001_001:ROOT_NUL|CHR_alienB001_001:RIG_NUL|CHR_alienB001_001:globalSRT_NUL|CHR_alienB001_001:globalSRT_CTRL ::: rotateX
connectAttr "|CHR_alienB001_001:ROOT_NUL|CHR_alienB001_001:RIG_NUL|CHR_alienB001_001:globalSRT_NUL|CHR_alienB001_001:globalSRT_CTRL.parentInverseMatrix" "|CHR_alienB001_001RNfosterParent1|globalSRT_CTRL_parentConstraint1.constraintParentInverseMatrix"  :::  |CHR_alienB001_001RNfosterParent1|globalSRT_CTRL_parentConstraint1 ::: constraintRotateY
connectAttr "|CHR_alienB001_001:ROOT_NUL|CHR_alienB001_001:RIG_NUL|CHR_alienB001_001:globalSRT_NUL|CHR_alienB001_001:globalSRT_CTRL.rotatePivot" "|CHR_alienB001_001RNfosterParent1|globalSRT_CTRL_parentConstraint1.constraintRotatePivot"  :::  |CHR_alienB001_001:ROOT_NUL|CHR_alienB001_001:RIG_NUL|CHR_alienB001_001:globalSRT_NUL|CHR_alienB001_001:globalSRT_CTRL ::: rotateY
connectAttr "|CHR_alienB001_001:ROOT_NUL|CHR_alienB001_001:RIG_NUL|CHR_alienB001_001:globalSRT_NUL|CHR_alienB001_001:globalSRT_CTRL.rotatePivotTranslate" "|CHR_alienB001_001RNfosterParent1|globalSRT_CTRL_parentConstraint1.constraintRotateTranslate"  :::  |CHR_alienB001_001RNfosterParent1|globalSRT_CTRL_parentConstraint1 ::: constraintRotateZ
```

Hope that helps!